# How to convert a .dat files with comma separated values into a .csv file?

Tags: scripting, csv

I have a `.dat` file like this.

```
    Name, Age, Place, Country
    A, 1, Ch, In
    B, 2, Ch, In
    C, 3, , In
```

I want to convert it into .csv file with *Name, Age, Place and Country* as the headers.

How to do that?

Comment: CSV literally means comma-separated values. Your `.dat` file is a CSV-file and the suffix is irrelevant as it is a text file in either case.

Comment: Are you possibly asking about removing the whitespace in between the fields and between the records?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file contains too many blanks and empty lines, you may remove these using `awk` and `csvformat` from the csvkit package:

```bash
$ cat file

    Name, Age, Place, Country

    A, 1, Ch, In

    B, 2, Ch, In

    C, 3, , In
```

```bash
$ awk 'NF' file | csvformat -S
Name,Age,Place,Country
A,1,Ch,In
B,2,Ch,In
C,3,,In
```

The `awk` command first reads the original data and outputs only the lines that contain something non-blank delimited by blanks.  This gets rid of empty lines.

The `csvformat` command then reformats the remaining data into a properly formatted CSV data set.  The `-S` (`--skipinitialspace`) option removes the initial space in the fields that have them.

This all assumes that your data does not contain fields with embedded commas or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.dat` file is already comma-separated so changing the suffix to `.csv` should be enough.

If you would like to remove the spaces and empty lines you could do something like this:

`cat input.txt | sed 's/ //g' | grep -v '^$' > output.txt`

Comment: Note that your pipeline would also remove any spaces characters _within_ fields.